# Multivariate Bisection

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

*cross post in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513660/multivariate-bisection-method)*

I need an algorithm to perform a 2D bisection method for solving a $2$x$2$ non-linear problem. Example: two equations $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ which I want to solve simultaneously. I have very familiar with the 1D bisection ( as well as other numerical methods ). Assume I already know the solution lies between the bounds $x_1 < x < x_2$ and $y_1 < y < y_2$.

In a grid the starting bounds are:

```
    ^
    |   C       D
y2 -+  o-------o
    |  |       |
    |  |       |
    |  |       |
y1 -+  o-------o
    |   A       B
    o--+------+---->
       x1     x2
```

and I know the values at $f(A)$, $f(B)$, $f(C)$ and $f(D)$ as well as $g(A)$, $g(B)$, $g(C)$ and $g(D)$. I might even know for which edges $f=0$ and for which $g=0$.

To start the bisection I guess we need to divide the points out along the edges as well as the middle.

```
    ^
    |   C   F   D
y2 -+  o---o---o
    |  |       |
    |G o   o M o H
    |  |       |
y1 -+  o---o---o
    |   A   E   B
    o--+------+---->
       x1     x2
```

Now considering the possibilities of combinations such as checking if $f(G)*f(M)<0$ `AND` $g(G)*g(M)<0$ seems overwhelming. Maybe I am making this a little too complicated, but I think there should be a multidimensional version of the Bisection, just as Newton-Raphson can be easily be multidimed using gradient operators.

Any clues, comments, or links are welcomed.

Comment: I suspect the "planar algebras" tag is not appropriate, although subfactor/quantum topology people would know better than I do.

Comment: Almost always for simultaneous nonlinear equations, the best method to use depends on the nature of $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$; without insight into the geometry of your functions near the roots, or even a way to come up with good starting points, you might end up chaotically exploring the plane (which is even more of a risk if the contours of your two bivariate functions have tangencies or near-tangencies to each other). That being said, I wish to direct your attention to Acton's "Numerical Methods that Work", most especially chapter 14. You might be able to pick up something useful there.

Comment: After some cursory searching: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2705 & http://www.springerlink.com/content/w72615872r512112/ ; as to whether you might be able to use them, you'll have to experiment.

Comment: The functions are continuous, one-to-one and monotonic as far as each independent variable, but non-linear. Sometimes they are near linear with a $x^{10/9}$ behavior.

Comment: Have you looked at the papers I pointed out to you?

Comment: @J.M. I have not, since I would have to buy them.

Answer (score 1):

A remarkable generalization of bisection to multiple dimensions is the subgradient method from convex optimization theory. If $f$ and $g$ are convex then $h = f^2 + g^2$ is also convex, and a simultaneous zero of $f$ and $g$ is a minimum of $h$.

Unfortunately, the subgradient method has more theoretical than practical value. But in a two-dimensional problem, it might do okay.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the vector field

$ \vec{F}(x,y) = (f(x,y), g(x,y)) $

and look for sources and sinks of $\vec{F}$. I think this could be done by recursively dividing up the plane into squares and calculating the winding number of each square. If it is nonzero then you have a critical point within that square (cf Thm 2 [this paper](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~ag4-gm/handouts/06gm_top3.pdf)) and should divide further.

Comment: Sorry, Dead link.

Comment: drats, maybe this will help: http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4485

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the pair of *opposite* corners to determine if zeroes lie within each of the four subdivided rectangles (zeroes can be there in more than one of them). Eg. if f(M)>0 and f(A)<0, then AEMG contains zeroes of f. Same is true also if f(G)>0 and f(E)<0.
2. Do this for all the four sub rectangles, and for both f and g.
3. There will be atleast one which contains zeroes for both f and g. Zoom into that and repeat.